# Using javascript to automatically send emails to user-defined fields in registration form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I am working with an Event Management System that was created by my workplace. There are different fields, some are default, others you can customize. Usually on completing the final registration page, a confirmation email is sent to the registrant.

In my current project, the registrant can invite a guest. So I would like a second email to be sent to the guest's email (which will be am auxilary field that the registrant will fill out). There are two different email templates, one to the original registrant and one to the guest. The message templates are identified by numbers: ex 101 and 102.

We are able to add custom javascript to the registration builder that should accomplish this goal, but I just cannot get it to work. We are supposed to be able to add event-custom CSS or custom jQuery, but any of the code I use will not let me send the second confirmation email.

The auxilary elements are given the identifiers css:Aux#01 with a "programmatic name" such as "guest-first-name". For this project the guest email is #Aux09 and the email template is 16344. The code I have so far is:

```
    $('#Aux09').on('keypress', function () {
    $('#sendToEmailAddress').val($('#Aux09').val());
    $('#CarbonCopyMessageID').val(16344);
    });
```

A standard registration confirmation is generated and sent to the registrant, however it's generating and sending the second email that is not working. Is there some basic code I'm missing, or is this too dependant on the Event management system?

Answer (score 0):

`.val(16344)` should be a string I think:

```
$('#Aux09').on('keypress', function () {
    $('#sendToEmailAddress').val($('#Aux09').val());
    $('#CarbonCopyMessageID').val('16344');
});
```

Comment: No sorry, that didn't work.
arrrghhh so frustrating!